# Context-free grammar producing a certain language

Tags: combinatorics, formal-languages, context-free-grammar

Is it possible to find a context-free grammar producing all words of form $a^nb^n a^n$, where $n \ge 0$? This question came up when I was trying to construct a grammar producing $\left\{ a,b \right\}^* - \left\{a^nb^n a^n: n\ge 0 \right\}$, which turned out to be a fairly easy task. Any hints greatly welcomed.

Comment: $\{a^nb^nc^n : n \geq 0 \}$ is a classic example used to illustrate the pumping lemma for context-free languages.  See, for instance, Hopcroft and Ullman's *Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation*.

Comment: this is very cool thank ypou